# A multi-line substitution in RST

Tags: include, substitution, restructuredtext

My document has a pattern that consists of a short paragraph followed by a few short bullet points. The pattern contains the same text wherever it's used in a given RST file, but is different in every file.

This should be a simple thing to mark up: define the text as a substitution in each file. But I can't find a way to define a substitution that does not fit on one line.

The [RST documentation in GitHub](https://sublime-and-sphinx-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reuse.html) says, "Use a Substitution to reuse short, inline content....
Include a Shared File to reuse longer, more complex content." There seems to be a black hole here, for text that is short and simple, not long and complex, but is not used inline.

I really don't want to use an include here; it would double the number of files in my project, with an include file for use in each source file. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed restriction to one line, but rST substitutions are limited to inline elements.

You may consider filing a [feature-request](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/feature-requests/).